# How would one set titles and default values inside of a select list?

Tags: html, css, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a way to set a default value (in a select list) that has to be switched out of in order for the 'required=""' attribute to be accepted and for the form to be submitted. In other words the default value can't stay as the chosen value. Also, how would one add titles to a select list that can not be chosen and are meant as a way of labeling the select options. Everything I am looking for is shown in the image below in case of confusion.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words the default value can't stay as the chosen value.

About this request, you could find this helpful.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
<select id="mySelect" required onchange="changeValue()">
  <option value="">Select a Country</option>
  <option value="c1">Country 1</option>
  <option selected value="c2">Country 2</option>
  <option value="c3">Country 3</option>
  <option value="c4">COuntry 4</option>
</select>
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" disabled>
</form>

<script>
function changeValue(){
    if (document.getElementById("mySelect").value != "")
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

If your selected value changes (just after the first time) and it's different from `""`, the submit button will be valid. This can also be accomplished with a flag instead of setting the property disable, it depends on what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking with javascript if the value = ""

Example from w3Schools.com:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Make sure you also validate on the server side! people could change the HTML / Javascript